# Sending Message With Audio Attachment

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, message, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to send a mp3 file with a message using UIActivityViewController. Here are the problems I am facing.

1. **When SMS is selected** from the UIActivityViewController, attachment and message appears in SMS application. But when I press the send button it never sends the message. Please note that I have two files one 2MB and 90sec duration other is 2.8MB 1220sec duration. The code works with the first one (2MB) but not with the second one (2.8MB). Am I missing something?
2. **If I select WhatsApp**

, the attachment never appears with the message.

**PS. Both the files has 'buildAction' property as 'BundledResource'.**

Here is the code:

```
    void uMessageController::SendTextMessage(string strTextMsg, "en-us",      eMessageType.Text)
    {
       try
       {
           string strDefaultMsg = "MyTest Message1"
           string strDefAttachmentName = "NYC";
           if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTextMsg))
           strTextMsg = strDefaultMsg;
           string strTextMsg1 = uShareMessages.GetMessageString  (strCulture);
           string existingSound =     NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource (strDefAttachmentName, "mp3");

            var remFileUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(existingSound);

            lstMessageItems = new System.Collections.Generic.List<NSObject> { new NSString(strTextMsg1 ?? string.Empty) };
            lstMessageItems.Add(remFileUrl);
            UIActivityViewController avController = new   UIActivityViewController(lstMessageItems.ToArray(), null);

            avController.ExcludedActivityTypes = vcActivitiesExcluded;
            avController.CompletionWithItemsHandler = ActivityViewController_CompletionHandler;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(avController, true, null);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            uShareMessages.ShowMessageBox("SendTextMessage", ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Thanks,
Paraclete

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

for **1.When SMS is selected**
I test your code in my side, and I can use [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIActivityViewController/) to share mp3 which is 6MB to the Message App. Please note that when we press the send button, it will go back and the message will send in the background. As you say that your first file can be sent successfully, please check if it is the problem of your second file?
for **2.If I select WhatsApp**
If we want to share files to a third party app, we should make sure if the app supports the file's type. Moreover different app has its own sharing features. In my test, WhatsApp will send one item at a time and will send message first. If you want to send the mp3 file, try to create the list with only one item(the url of the mp3 file) then test it again.